# StatusStrip is truncating the error message needed to display. How to make longer?

Tags: vb.net, toolstrip, statusstrip

I tried to make this phone validation program for my first VB class. I need to make this happen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd86E.png

but unfortunately this happens and the message truncates. Is there a way to fix this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFQDx.png

Answer (score 0):

-smaller font

-bigger window

-less text

-make it scroll

The possibilities are endless... :)

Comment: Thats a different question , you should make a new post. Or even better, search the existing and put in some effort; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408639/is-there-any-visual-basic-2008-scrolling-text-code